# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Tags: php

I got this error when debugging my code:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in order.php on line 72

Here is a snippet of the code (starting on line 72):

```
$purchaseOrder = new PurchaseOrderFactory->instance();
$arrOrderDetails = $purchaseOrder->load($customerName);
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to call a method on an object just created with `new` before PHP 5.4.

In PHP 5.4 and later, the following can be used:

```
$purchaseOrder = (new PurchaseOrderFactory)->instance();
```

Note the mandatory pair of parenthesis.

In previous versions, you have to call the method on a variable:

```
$purchaseFactory = new PurchaseOrderFactory;
$purchaseOrder = $purchaseFactory->instance();
```

Comment: Even if he used his code on PHP 5.4 that would generate a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

change to as your syntax was invalid:

```
$purchaseOrder = PurchaseOrderFactory::instance();
$arrOrderDetails = $purchaseOrder->load($customerName);
```

where presumably `instance()` creates an instance of the class. You can do this rather than saying `new`

Comment: this code works for php 4.9 version. But why does this error occur?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use (it's invalid php syntax):

```
new PurchaseOrderFactory->instance();
```

You probably meant one of those:

```
// Initialize new object of class PurchaseOrderFactory
new PurchaseOrderFactory(); 

// Clone instance of already existing PurchaseOrderFactory
clone  PurchaseOrderFactory::instance();

// Simply use one instance
PurchaseOrderFactory::instance();

// Initialize new object and that use one of its methods
$tmp = new PurchaseOrderFactory();
$tmp->instance();
```