# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ')'

Tags: php, syntax

I keep getting an error when I try to add a blog entry into my database. I have a simple syntax highlighter but it is not showing where something is not right.

Error:
`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ')' on line 75 and 71`

My script:

```
if(!isset($error)){

try {

    //insert into database
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog_posts (postTitle,postDesc,postCont,postDate) VALUES (:postTitle, :postDesc, :postCont, :postDate)') ; //line 71
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':postTitle' => $postTitle,
        ':postDesc' => $postDesc,
        ':postCont' => $postCont,
        ':postDate' => (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') //Line 75
    ));

    //redirect to index page
    header('Location: index.php?action=posted&title='.$postTitle.'');
    exit;

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

}
```

Comment: `(new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` <--- where did you see such a syntax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T\_OBJECT\_OPERATOR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388541/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-object-operator)

Comment: @zerkms this syntax exists in Laravel, probably the OP was trying to apply the framework logic into plain php.

Comment: @zerkms Hi again, in the following link you can find a usage example of the type `(new Model)->method()`, https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1436 , look for the first comment from May 29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your usage of [format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) is wrong, change:

```
...
':postDate' => (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

to

```
...
$date = new DateTime();
$formattedDate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
....
':postDate' => $formattedDate
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem. I see why that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$today = (new \DateTime('NOW'))->format('d-m-y');
```