# Facebook login PHP sdk 4.4

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I have been trying to test the Facebook PHP login system but keep getting the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /xxxxx/httpd.www/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php on line 146

I have read through several different examples and tried to implement each after first running into this as well as read through the different questions/answers on here all to no avail.

If anyone has ran into this and found a solution or knows of the solution i would much appreciate the pointer.

**Edit** current code added.

```
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'xxx','xxx' );

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;


// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://somesite.com/index.php' );

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

  // print data
  echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
}
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13388570/

Comment: @Fred-ii- im using PHP 5.6

Comment: If you are using PHP 5.6 you must have changed something to FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php

Answer (score 1):

I got the same question with you.you can not use the "include" like in old version. In v4.4,they use it like this:

```
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '/path/to/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/path/to/facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php';
```

and then ,just the same as you

```
    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\GraphUser;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
```

That is all!
reference:[Facebook SDK for PHP](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4)

Comment: It was my bad my host for the new domain put the PHP down to PHP 5.3 but ty