# syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR? Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, oop, facebook-graph-api, object

I am practicing with facebook PHP api

when i am trying to make a login function
here comes out this warnning

syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /home/u528851895/public_html/Desktap/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php on line 137

but it's ok when i use mamp localhost

here's line 136~138 in FacebookResponse.php:

```
  public function getGraphObject($type = 'Facebook\GraphObject') {
    return (new GraphObject($this->responseData))->cast($type);
  }
```

Comment: The server at your ISP is running an earlier version of PHP that doesn't support dereferencing. You need to create the object then call the method as two separate statements. Or upgrade your ISP's PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T\_OBJECT\_OPERATOR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388541/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-object-operator)

Comment: thx a lot!!
maybe i ll update the version of php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your php version or do something like this

```
public function getGraphObject($type = 'Facebook\GraphObject') {
    $obj = new GraphObject($this->responseData);
    return $obj->cast($type);
  }
```