# CakePHP 3 showing white blank page

Tags: cakephp

I have successfully installed CakePHP 3 on my local machine. I use WAMP server (http: // localhost /). Everything works fine.
When I have transferred the same files to a web server via FTP  http://example.com/ cakephp 3 does not work, it shows the white blank page.
Web server (example.com) uses php 5.6 version.
Where is the problem? What's wrong?

Comment: Check your PHP/Server logs.

Comment: This could be one of a dozen things.  I'd start by checking the logs, as already mentioned, and then file permissions i.e. can the app/tmp (if that's still in version 3) be written to for the cache and logs?

Comment: These are my steps:
1. Download composer.phar in wamp/www/
2. Composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app cakephp3
3. http://localhost/cakephp3/ - I received a welcome message. Everything works fine.
4. After successful installation I transferred the same files to a web server via FTP http://example1.com/
5. Cakephp 3 shows the white blank page.
6. I tried to do the same thing with other web servers (FTP transfer)  http://example2.com/
7. Cakephp 3 shows error massage: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /home/user/public_html/test/config/bootstrap.php on line 107

Comment: this is my 107 line: (new ConsoleErrorHandler(Configure::read('Error')))->register();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T\_OBJECT\_OPERATOR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388541/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-object-operator)

Comment: This indicates that your server does does _not_ use PHP 5.6, but PHP < 5.4.

Comment: It seems to be a problem in the version of PHP. PHP version should be greater than 5.4. It seems that the server example1.com not using version 5.6. I made a test on the third server example3.com. Cakephp 3 is installed successfully. Php version is 5.6

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue before and it is was due to the PHP version being too low. If you are running CakePHP 3, ensure your server version is at 5.6 or higher. You can do this in cPanel if you are on shared hosting.
GoDaddy as an example, look under the Software section then you should see "Select PHP version".

Also, ensure you set the correct permission for your `tmp` and `log` folder under your CakePHP root.