# Laravel Abstract Class Repository

Tags: php, laravel, abstract-class, repository-pattern

Hi I'm trying to implement the repository pattern in laravel with abstract class to have some base functions which is I'm new at.

I'm getting

> Parse error:syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

on the line AbstractRepository->create($request);
when I call the function from the abstract in the repository. Here are the codes

AbstractRepository.php

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Abstracts;

    use App\Exceptions\NoResourceFoundException;
    use App\Exceptions\ResourceNotFoundException;

    abstract class AbstractRepository
    {

        /**
         * @var Model
         */
        protected $model;

        /**
         * @var array
         */
        public $errors = [];

        /**
         * @param Model $model
         */
        public function __construct(Model $model)
        {
            $this->model = $model;
        }

        public function create(array $data)
        {
            return $this->model->create($data);
        }
   }
```

ReportRepositoryInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Interfaces;

interface ReportRepositoryInterface {

  public function createReport (array $data);
}
?>
```

ReportRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Interfaces\ReportRepositoryInterface;
use App\Models\Report;
use App\Services\ApiResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Abstracts\AbstractRepository;

class ReportRepository implements ReportRepositoryInterface {

  public function createReport(array $request){
    AbstractRepository->create($request);
    return ApiResponse::responseData($request, 'Record successfully created!');
  }
}

?>
```

ReportsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Interfaces\ReportRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class ReportsController extends Controller
{

  public function __construct(ReportRepositoryInterface $report, Request $request)
  {
    $this->report = $report;
    $this->request = $request;
  }

  public function createReport()
  {
    $data = $this->request->all();
        return $this->report->createReport($data);
  }
}
```

Can anyone enlighten me? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T\_OBJECT\_OPERATOR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388541/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-object-operator)

Comment: `PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4`

Comment: Isn't it better to have a Trait here? I'm just wondering about this topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a class is `abstract` that means that you cannot create an instance of that class directly, not that you can call the methods of the class without creating an instance of the class, that would be a `static` method. An `abstract` class is meant to be extended. In this case, your `ReportRepository` needs to be modified to be:

```
class ReportRepository extends AbstractRepository implements ReportRepositoryInterface {

    public function createReport(array $request){
        $this->create($request);
        return ApiResponse::responseData($request, 'Record successfully created!');
    }
}
```

Take a look at the manual for [abstraction](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) and the manual for [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) method visibility.

Comment: worked but now im getting Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\AbstractsReporistory::__construct must be an instance of App\Abstracts\Model, instance of App\Models\Report given, in AppServiceProvider. Report model already extends AbstractModel

Comment: AppServiceProvider looks like this   `$app->bind(ReportRepositoryInterface::class, function ($app) {
          return new ReportRepository(new Report());
      });`

Comment: You may find it more constructive in the long-term to initially take a beginner's approach to learning basic php/programming concepts rather than diving into a Laravel project and working through the many issues that will arise.  Having said that, your new issue is related to namespaces.  Specifically, a qualified path hasn't been specified for Model so it's attempting to locate the class in its current namespace.  More info on namespaces in general can be found at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: i think i am already using the namespaces properly. code looks like this

AbstractModel.php
`<?php

namespace App\Abstracts;

use App\Exceptions\NoResourceFoundException;
use App\Exceptions\ResourceNotFoundException;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

abstract class AbstractModel extends Model
{
}`

ReportModel.php
`<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Abstracts\AbstractModel;

class Report extends AbstractModel
{
}`

Comment: Never mind. I fixed it. added a protected $model and construct on the repository

Comment: Putting the constructor on the parent repository is actually better then putting it on the abstract base repository because you can enforce which model you want to have injected into the repository.