# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in mail.php on line 4

Tags: php, object, swiftmailer

Am creating a file to send email with `swift mailer`. I got a error like

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in mail.php on line 4

But it working in `xampp` localhost

this is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'swift/lib/swift_required.php';
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl'))
  ->setUsername('example@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword('password')
  ;
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
      ->setFrom(array('example@domain.com' => 'Name'))
      ->setTo(array('example1@domain.com'=> 'A name'))
      ->setBody('Test Message Body')
    ;
$result = $mailer->send($message);
?>
```

My hosting version is `PHP 5.2.17`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388541/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-object-operator

Comment: sift this on server it may be xammp not updated

Comment: @SebastianBrosch: Thank you to sharing this link already i tried this but same error

Comment: You tried *what exactly* that's still giving the error?

Comment: FWIW, you should be upgrading your server from 5.2 to something newer ASAP. PHP 5.2 is ancient and unsupported, meaning it doesn't even receive necessary security updates anymore.

Comment: @deceze: Am change `$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl'))` to  `$t = new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl');
$transport = ($t)`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in \mail.php on line 5

Comment: `$transport = ($t)`…?! And then what…?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148284/discussion-between-ramesh-s-and-deceze).

Comment: @deceze `$t = new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl');
$transport = ($t)
  ->setUsername('example@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword('password')
  ;`

Comment: Stick to the syntax in the duplicate, don't make up your own syntax.