# Partial amount of PHP visible on webpage

Tags: php

At the very bottom I have posted what is visible on the webpage. Not sure what I'm doing, I will post other .php files that are linked to this if necessary. The webpage is also unusable, clicking login will do nothing except refresh the page. Not sure what changed but it was working before adding a few lines of code. I had trouble with new on login.php which accesses my database with connect.php

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        
        include("classes/connect.php");
        include("classes/login.php");
        
        $email = "";
        $password = "";
        
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
        {
            
            $login = new Login();
            $result = $login->evaluate($_POST);
            
            if($result != "")
            {
                echo "<div style='text-align:center;font-size:12px;color:white;background-color:grey;'>";
                echo "<br>The following errors occured:<br><br>";
                echo $result;
                echo "</div>";
            }else
            {
                
                header("Location: profile.php");
                die;
            }
        
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        
        }
        
    ?>
```

This is what is displayed at the top of the webpage

'''

```
evaluate($_POST);
            
            if($result != "")
            {
                echo "
    else
            {
                
                header("Location: profile.php");
                die;
            }
        
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        
        }
        
    ?>
```

'''
My login.php class starting throwing errors due to changing

```
'''
    $DB = new Database();
    $result = DB->read($query);
'''
```

to
'''

```
  $DB = Database();
            $result = (new db)->read($query);
```

'''
Here is the login.php class I have stored in my classes folder
'''

```
<?php

class Login
{
    
        private $error = "";
    
    
    public function evaluate($data)
    {
        
        $email = addsLashes($data['email']);
        $password = addsLashes($data['password']);
        
        $query = "select * from users where email = '$email' limit 1 ";
        
        $DB = Database();
        $result = (new db)->read($query);
        
        if($result)
        {
            
            $row = $result[0];
            
            if($password == $row['password'])
            {
                
                //create session data
                $_SESSION['site_userid'] = $row['userid'];
                
            }else
            {
                $error .= "wrong password<br>";
            }
        }else
        {
            $error .= "No such email was found<br>";
        }
            
            return $error;
        
    }
}
```

'''
This is able to connect to the database using the code from connect.php where I created the Database class
'''

```
<?php

class Database
{
    
private $host = "localhost";
private $username = "root";
private $password = "root";
private $db = "site_db";

    function connect()
    {

        $connection = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password,$this->db);
        return $connection;
    }

    function read($query) 
    {
        $conn = $this->connect();
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        
        if(!$result)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
                $data = false;
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    
                    $data[] = $row;
                    
                }

                return $data;
        }
    }
    
    function save($query) 
    {
        $conn = $this->connect();
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        
        if(!$result)
        {
            return false;
        }else
        {
                return true;
        }
    }
    
}

?>
```

'''
I really think changing the new function messed everything up. I am following a tutorial which did not use (new db) and just new Database. Using new Database will throw a fatal error.

Comment: The part after `?>` is what appears on your page?

Comment: I've tested your code and nothing is displayed. So I think the problem is in your login.php or you have a different code in your server.

Comment: Yes, after ?> that code is displayed at the top. I think it might be login.php as well since that is where I first had trouble updating new to (new)

Comment: Here is where I learned to change the code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388541/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-object-operator/13388570

Comment: If you got `$email = addsLashes($data['email']);` from a tutorial, then throw that tutorial away now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a copy/paste error where there's some duplicate code.

Is the following what you want?

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    
    include("classes/connect.php");
    include("classes/login.php");
    
    $email = "";
    $password = "";
    
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        
        $login = new Login();
        $result = $login->evaluate($_POST);
        
        if($result != "")
        {
            echo "<div style='text-align:center;font-size:12px;color:white;background-color:grey;'>";
            echo "<br>The following errors occured:<br><br>";
            echo $result;
            echo "</div>";
        }else
        {
            
            header("Location: profile.php");
            die;
        }
    
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    
    }
    
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not duplicate code at the bottom below the closing ?> Php tag, it is just what's being displayed on the webpage